# How to properly test JPA/JSF webapp with Maven, Jetty, HtmlUnit?

Tags: maven, jetty, htmlunit

I'm trying to use Maven, Jetty and HtmlUnit to test a webapp written using JPA2.0, JSF. I am confused as to how to do it properly. For example, I get dramatically different results depending on which version of `maven-jetty-plugin` i use:

6.1.x: error during tests, cannot parse basic JSF...

```
Running xxx.xxx.my.functional.HtmlUnitTest
2011-06-03 19:41:54.741:WARN::/project1/index.html
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /index.xhtml 
@37,60 value="#{item.availability.toString()}" Error Parsing: 
#{item.availability.toString()}
```

7.0.0.pre5 (or preanything, really): supposedly starts, then silently hangs (I have to kill it).

```
[INFO] Starting jetty 7.0.0.pre5 ...
2011-06-03 19:50:59.035::INFO:  jetty-7.0.0.pre5
2011-06-03 19:51:18.381::INFO:  No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2011-06-03 19:51:20 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.0 (FCS 20110303) for context '/projekt1'
2011-06-03 19:51:21 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp
INFO: JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.
2011-06-03 19:51:21.389::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Any suggestion would be welcome, as trivial "tests" (`Assert.assertTrue(true)`, i.e. no real testing whatsoever) do pass and jetty stops after testing successfully.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm running into the same issue now... being that i'm getting the ELResolvers for JSF were not registered, but using jetty-6.1.25.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont remember how it exactly went from there, but I ended up using glassfish. Anyway, I think I'd post the solution if I had one, so no luck there. Perhaps Brians answer below is _the_ answer, but I have no way to check right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to pop in and let you know that if you're trying to run Mojarra (JSF) 2.1.0 under tomcat or Jetty; that it is imcompatible.  See this link [Mojarra Known Issues](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.0/issues.html).  "This release of Mojarra is not known to work in Apache Tomcat or Jetty. Tomcat and Jetty support will be restored in a future release. It is known to work in Oracle WebLogic and Oracle GlassFish."

Mojarra 2.1.1+ fixed this issue, even though it claims to be still unresolved.  I have mojarra 2.1.4 (current as of 12/1/11) running on tomcat 6.0.33 presently.  See this [post](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) by BalusC for some details about the mojarra fix.

Also, I believe that JSF1027 info warning you are getting is because of the context parameter in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
<param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value></context-param>
```

I commented it out in my web.xml and poof, no more JSF1027 (The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.) errors; and EL still resolves on my JSF pages. :)

Comment: I currently have no way to test your solution, but it seems highly probable I overlooked the "known issue" ;) so you do get the tick mark ;)

Comment: yeah...i think this is actually the correct answer. when you had this in your web.xml, did you have the el-api/el-impl dependencies in your pom?

Comment: @mikesir87 Yes, I already included the el dependencies in my pom file. Maybe it was expecting to be registered for JSP as well if you explicitly choose to register it for JSF?

Comment: OK, just another thought. Scratch what I said about removing the context-param; I have that in place to use EL 2.2 under tomcat6; which it wasn't designed for, but with some hacks, can be made to work.  You'll get that warning because el 2.2 was made to be used with jsp spec 2.2, and tomcat 6 only supports jsp spec 2.1; which is why I get the warning.  I had to re-enable it in order to support method parameters in EL.